# wcf maxReceivedMessageSize Limit

Tags: wcf, web-config, streaming, limits

As far as I know the limit on `maxReceivedMessageSize` property is limited by max int size which is 2147483647 bytes (2gb) I'm hoping this information is not correct as I'm typing it .

In my application I need to send files over this size limit, I need to be able to send more than 4-5 gb files. Is there any workaround for that? or should I follow another approach? I am really stuck here.

Even if my `maxReceivedMessageSize` limit is 2gb now my service throws out of memory exception at 1.5 gb both while uploading and downloading. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

For sending large files through WCF the **streaming transfer** should be used. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx about how to make stream transfer

Comment: I already checked this article. im using streamed transferMode already. but thanks anyways..

Comment: Try using any compression techniques such as lzma if you are ready to use 3rd party dlls.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen but what exception are you having than? The trouble is not in maxReceivedMessageSize. Do you have a trace log?